# How can I extract first and last line from multiple text blocks separated with new line?

Tags: sed

I have a file containing multiple tests with detailed action written one beneath another. All test blocks are separated one from another by new line. I want to extract only first and last line from the all blocks and put it on one line for each block into a new file. Here is an example:

**input.txt**:

```
[test1]
duration
summary
code=
Results= PASS

[test2]
duration
summary=x
code=
Results=FAIL

.....

[testX]
duration
summary=x
code=
Results= PASS
```

**output.txt** should be sometime like this:

```
test1 PASS
test2 FAIL
...
testX PASS
```

eg2:

```
[Linux_MP3Enc_xffv.2_Con_37_003]
type = testcase
summary = MP3 encoder test
ActionGroup[Linux_Enc] = PASS
ActionGroup[Linux_Playb] = PASS
ActionGroup[Linux_Pause_Resume] = PASS
ActionGroup[Linux_Fast_Seek] = PASS
Duration = 230.607398987 s
Total_Result = PASS

[Composer__vtx_007]
type = testcase
summary = composer
Background[0xff000000] = PASS
Background[0xffFFFFFF] = PASS
Background[0xffFF0000] = PASS
Background[0xff00FF00] = PASS
Background[0xff0000FF] = PASS
Background[0xff00FFFF] = PASS
Background[0xffFFFF00] = PASS
Background[0xffFF00FF] = PASS
Duration = 28.3567230701 s
Total_Result = PASS


[Videox_Rotate_008]
type = testcase
summary = rotation
Rotation[0] = PASS
Rotation[1] = PASS
Rotation[2] = PASS
Rotation[3] = PASS
Duration = 14.0116529465 s
Total_Result = PASS
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple `gnu awk`:

```
awk -F= -v RS='' '{print $1 $NF}' file
[Linux_MP3Enc_xffv.2_Con_37_003] PASS
[Composer__vtx_007] PASS
[Videox_Rotate_008] PASS
```

If you do not like the brackets:

```
awk -F'[]=[]' -v RS='' '{print $2 $NF}' file
Linux_MP3Enc_xffv.2_Con_37_003 PASS
Composer__vtx_007 PASS
Videox_Rotate_008 PASS
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! I am a new user so can't give you +1 because I have less than 15 reputation. 

PS: All the solutions were great. Thank you guys! (+ to everyone)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using a regular expression such as:

```
(?<testId>test\d+)(?:.*\n){4}.*(?<outcome>PASS|FAIL)
```

The regex matches your sample output and stores the test id (e.g. "test1") in the capture group named "testId" and the outcome (e.g. "PASS") in the capture group "outcome".

([Test it in regexr](http://regexr.com/4q0e0))

The regex can be used in any language with regex support. The below code shows how to do it in Python.

([Test it in repl.it](https://repl.it/@knallle/StackOverflow-59153720))

```py
import re

# Read from input.txt
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
  indata = f.read()

# Modify the regex slightly to fit Python regex syntax
pattern = '(?:.*)(?P<testId>test\d+)(?:.*\n){4}.*(?P<outcome>PASS|FAIL)'

# Get a generator which yeilds all matches
matches = re.finditer(pattern, indata)

# Combine the matches to a list of strings
outputs = ['{} {}'.format(m.group('testId'), m.group('outcome')) for m in matches]

# Join all rows to one string
output = '\n'.join(outputs)

# Write to output.txt
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(output)
```

Running the above script on `input.txt` containing:

```
[test1]
duration
summary
code=
Results= PASS

[test2]
duration
summary=x
code=
Results=FAIL

[test444]
duration
summary=x
code=
Results= PASS
```

yields a file `output.txt` containing:

```
test1 PASS
test2 FAIL
test444 PASS
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice implementation for this particular example but I forgot to mention that test name changes from one block to another, and also the block number of lines, that's why I asked about first and last line from the block.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` as tagged (although other tools would probably be more natural to use) :

```
sed -nE '/^\[.*\]$/h;s/^Results= ?//;t r;b;:r;H;x;s/\n/ /;p'
```

Explanation :

```
/^\[.*\]$/h         # matches the [...] lines, put them in the hold buffer
s/^Results= ?//     # matches the Results= lines, discards the useless part
t r;b               # on lines which matched, jump to label r; 
                    # otherwise jump to the end (and start processing the next line)
:r;H;x;s/\n/ /;p    # label r; append the pattern space (which contains the end of the Results= line)
                    # to the hold buffer. Switch Hold buffer and pattern space,
                    # replace the linefeed in the pattern space by a space and print it
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/JfffZ3).

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations! (+)

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the first and last line from the block, how about:

```
awk -v RS="" '{
    n = split($0, a, /\n/)
    print a[1]
    print a[n]
}' input.txt
```

Result for the 1st example:

```
[Linux_MP3Enc_xffv.2_Con_37_003]
Total_Result = PASS
[Composer__vtx_007]
Total_Result = PASS
[Videox_Rotate_008]
Total_Result = PASS
```

The man page of `awk` tells:

> If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated  by  blank  lines.

You can easily split the block with blank lines with this feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations! (+1). It was very helpful.